# Cannot Save MetaBox Data in Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I've been working on this issue for quite a while and am truly stumped.  Below is all of the code for my custom post type:

```
/* Services Post Type */

function services_post_type() {
$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Services', 'service' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Service', 'service' ),
'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'service' ),
'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Service', 'service' ),
'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Service', 'service' ),
'new_item' => _x( 'New Service', 'service' ),
'view_item' => _x( 'View Service', 'service' ),
'search_items' => _x( 'Search Services', 'service' ),
'not_found' => _x( 'No services found', 'service' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No services found in Trash', 'service' ),
'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Service:', 'service' ),
'menu_name' => _x( 'Services', 'service' ),
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => false,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'has_archive' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'can_export' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post'
);
register_post_type( 'service', $args );
} 
add_action( 'init', 'services_post_type' );

/*
 * Custom meta boxes 
*/

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'create_meta_boxes' );

function create_meta_boxes() {
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', __('Service Price'), 'meta_box_info', 'service', 'normal', 'low' );
}


// Create meta box: Service Price

function meta_box_info( $post ) {

$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
?>

<?php $text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_box_info', true); ?>
<p>Price: <input type="text" name="meta_box_info" id="meta_box_info" size="25" /></p>

<?php   
}

// Save meta box: Service Price

function save_my_metadata($ID = false, $post = false)
{
if($post->post_type != 'service')
    return;
update_post_meta($ID, 'my_metadata', $_POST['my_metadata']);
}
```

Comment: (A) You didn't attach it to a hook - is this missing just in here? (B) Look at examples for the `save_post` action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kaiser pointed out, you need to use the `save_post` hook to call your `save_my_metadata()` function.

See this code sample for a complete example of saving (and validating) metabox data:

https://github.com/Veraxus/nv-example-meta-box/blob/master/init.php